# How does typedef work internally?

Tags: c

As the question goes how does `typedef` work internally?

PS : I did search in various websites including Wikipedia and various. But none of them answer this. Hence the question.

To clarify further : I did get to what it does but how it does is the question.

Comment: This is highly compiler specific. You should specify a compiler, otherwise this question is pointless.

Comment: Since the `typedef` concept does not extend past compile time, all `typedef` does is inserting an additional type alias into a [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) of the compiler. There is nothing else to it, really.

Comment: A good (but hard) solution is probably for you to download the source code to GCC and look for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is the keyword in `C`, which provides the programmer a tool to make an alias of own

`data type` from the other types or existing built-in types.

This is how the language is and this is how it's implemented.

`typedef <given_type> <new_type>`

FYI : if you do

`int a` it parsed by compiler and then it came to know that `a` is a variable of type `int`.
And accordingly memory is assigned and all.

Similarly whenever `typedef` keyword found then it assumes that the type just following it is the `old_type` and other new identifier is `new_type`.

EDIT :

ISO c99 : Storage-class specifiers

`The typedef specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class specifier’’ for syntactic convenience
only.If, in a parameter declaration, an identifier can be treated either as a typedef name or as a parameter name, it shall be taken as a typedef name.A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified`

Comment: does not answer my question though.

Comment: `typedef` does not create a type; it defines an alias for a type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : Thanks corrected , it's already mentioned in c-Standard.

Answer (score 0):

How any compiler handles a `typedef` isn't specified; most likely the type information is saved as part of the symbol table entry for that name, and everywhere the type name is encountered in the source code, the equivalent type information is substituted during translation.